# getContext() is NULL for a certain fragment flow

Tags: android, android-fragments

2 Fragments & 1 Activity are involved. Here is the flow wherein I am able to reproduce the issue, along with relevant code snippets.

@1. From Frag1, open Frag2

```
Frag2 fragment = Frag2.newInstance(pos);
BaseFragment.addToBackStack(getContext(), fragment);
```

Here is BaseFragment.addToBackStack()

```
BaseFragment

public static void addToBackStack(Context context, BaseFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((BaseActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(BaseActivity.getContainerIdForCurrentActivity(context), fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

@2. Press Back to open Frag1 again.

@3. Open Activity A1 with `startActivityForResult()` from an Adapter in Frag1.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Act1.class);
    intent.putExtra(..);
    intent.putExtra(..);
    ((BaseActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, Frag1.REQ_CODE_ISSUE_DONE);
```

@4. Go back to Frag1, either by pressing Back or finishing A1 with 
`setResult()`

@5. `onActivityResult()` of Frag1 is called. But inside it, both `getContext()` and `getActivity()` are NULL.

```
Frag1

if (resultCode == Ac1.RESULT_CODE_OPEN_LANDING_SCREEN) {
            if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
                BaseFragment.replaceStack(getContext(), landingFrag.newInstance());
            } else {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
```

If A1 is opened directly from Frag1, then `getContext()` is NOT null inside `startActivityForResult()` and works perfectly.

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=792, result=135, data=null} to activity {in.shadowfax.gandalf/in.shadowfax.gandalf.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
                                                                          at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
                                                                          at in.shadowfax.gandalf.help.issues.IssuesFrag.onActivityResult(IssuesFrag.java:153)
                                                                          at in.shadowfax.gandalf.help.HelpPresenter.triggerIssuesFragOnActivityResult(HelpPresenter.java:72)
                                                                          at in.shadowfax.gandalf.help.HelpFrag.onActivityResult(HelpFrag.java:100)
                                                                          at in.shadowfax.gandalf.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:901)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getContext()`

Comment: Can't use `getApplicationContext()`. Need to use `if (getActivity() instanceOf MainActivity) {..}`

Comment: post your logcat and complete navigation code

Comment: Added logcat. Happens due to NULL context

Comment: you have exception in `android.content.Context.getPackageName()` . Post your `onActivityResult()` code of `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Added `onActivityResult()` snippet for Frag1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141872/discussion-between-anand-savjani-and-ishaan-garg).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
((BaseActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, Frag1.REQ_CODE_ISSUE_DONE);
```

using

```
fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, Frag1.REQ_CODE_ISSUE_DONE);
```

solved the issue.

`onActivityResult()` inside Nested Fragments is now called in support lib 23.2. So no need to reroute the `onActivityResult()` from Actvity to frag manually as I was doing in my case.

Ref: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/onactivityresult-nested-fragment-support-library-v23.2/en